# adding and maintaining named strings in a seperate class file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, hardcoded

I have developed an asp.net web application containing 40-50 pages. I have implemented logger using Log4net and each of my pages has this in its page_load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            log.Debug("In Page Load Function");
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["OrgId"] != null)
                {
                   // my logic
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Homepage.aspx?Sid=1", false);
                }
                log.Debug("Page load function successfull");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

This method has many strings like `"In page Load function","OrgId","Homepage.aspx?Sid=1","Page load function successfull"`.  Now i would like to maintain these string which are common throughout my application in a seperate class file and use it with a variable...

Can you suggest what class can be used for this or your way of handling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a base page that has this function, where you have `// my logic` add a call to an abstract method (`load_page`, for instance). Then subclass all of your other pages from this and override `load_page` from them, have it containing all the logic you need.

This will keep all of these strings in one place, though I don't see why you would need to change them to variables.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe storing your strings in a resource file would help. Example [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1683.htm).
You could also think of inheriting that behavior from a base class.